# What card do I need to attach SATA drives to server

Tags: motherboard, sata, pci-express, hardware-raid, ibm-server

I have `IBM System x3650 M2` and it has only SAS drives attached

It has `7 PCI-e` empty slots.

I want to know what type of card I need which I can put in PCI-E so that I can join 2 SATA drives of higher capacity like `4TB or 3TB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None.

You need no extra card. A SAS connector accept both SAS and SATA drives.

Should all SAS connectors already  be filled then you have the choice between:

- PCI-e SATA cards (no RAID)
- PCI-e SATA RAID cards.
- PCI-e SAS cards (no RAID)
- PCI-e SAS RAID cards.
- Port multipliers between the current SAS connectors and the SAS drives.

(SATA drives on port multipliers also work but are **NOT** recommended since SATA can fail non-gracefully and block access to all drives on the [port multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier).)

Answer (score 0):

You need a SATA RAID controller that can handle those sized drives.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. It also depends on the server and its backplane as many SAS controllers already support SATA so you might not need anything other than the correct cables.

Comment: Seriously? You have the technical details and you want me to tell you what it says? All you have to do is CTRL+F and look for the info you need.